# How to finish $(x+2y)dx-xdy=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am a bit confused, should be really easy but one step:

$$(x+2y)dx-xdy =0\tag{1}$$

substitute:
$$y = tx$$
derivative:
$$dy =xdt+tdx$$

substitute everything in $(1)$ I got:

$$(x+2tx)dx - x(xdt+tdx)=0$$

Pulling $x$ out:

$$(1+2t)dx = (xdt+tdx)$$

And that is where I'm stuck...

Comment: Separate the variables as:$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dt}{1+t}$

Answer (score 1):

$$(1+2t)dx=(xdt+tdx)\Rightarrow(1+t)dx=xdt$$

$$\Rightarrow\int\frac 1xdx=\int\frac 1{1+t}dt+C$$

$$\Rightarrow \ln |x|=\ln |1+t|+C\Rightarrow |x|=|1+t|e^C \\\ \\\Rightarrow x^2=c|x+y|$$

Comment: You had $(1+2t)dx=xdt+tdx$ so $[(1+2t)dx=xdt+tdx]\~-tdx\implies (1+2t)dx-tdx=xdt\implies (1+2t-t)dx=xdt\implies (1+t)dx=xdt$

Comment: @Holo, so it means we just group parts with the same differentials?

Comment: @d.sci yes, just rearrange the variables to a form we can solve. In this case is grouping up everything with $dx$ on one side and everything with $dt$ on the other

Answer (score 1):

If we assume $x\neq 0$ then we can rewrite the equation to

$$(x+2y)dx−xdy=0 \implies (x+2y)=x\dfrac{dy}{dx}$$
$$\implies \dfrac{dy}{dx} = 1+2y/x$$

Now substitute $y(x)=xz(x) \implies \dfrac{dy}{dx} = z(x) + x\dfrac{dz}{dx} = 1 + 2(xz)/x$

$$\implies z + x\dfrac{dz}{dx}=1+2z$$
$$\implies \dfrac{dz}{dx}=\dfrac{1+z}{x}$$
$$\implies \dfrac{dz}{1+z} = \dfrac{dx}{x}$$

The last equation can be integrated

$$\ln(1+z(x)) - \ln(1+z(x_0))=\ln x - \ln x_0=\ln\dfrac{x}{x_0}$$
$$1+z(x) = (1+z(x_0))\dfrac{x}{x_0}$$

Resubstitution with $z(x)=y(x)/x$ and solving for $y(x)$ will yield the solution.